# notify-send doesn't work in crontab (doesn't send a notification)

Tags: bash, unix, cron, notify, pacman-package-manager

I want to make a little script which send me a notification when an update is available for pacman. I did that :

```
#!/bin/sh

while /usr/bin/inotifywait -e create /var/lib/pacman; do
/usr/bin/notify-send "pacmauto" "Updating...";
updateDone=0
while /usr/bin/inotifywait -e delete /var/lib/pacman -t 30; do
    updateDone=1;
done
if [ $updateDone -eq 1 ]; then
    /usr/bin/notify-send "pacmauto" "Update done, you can install it with pacman -Su";
fi
done
```

But the fact is when i use it with my user prompt, it works. But when i want to put it in a crontab, it doesn't send me a notification when it's done. Someone can help me ?

Comment: Maybe you will find this usefull: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1533494

Comment: I suggest you add the answer bellow so that people will find a solution if ever they en up on this thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally, I follow this topic (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1533494) and it works now. Thanks you Philibobby !

Comment: So the main problem was letting cron know which display to use.
Thank you for coming back and answering your own question.